# Why I can take address of *v.begin() where v is a std::vector

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, stdvector, rvalue

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
int f()
{
    int* a = new int(3);
    return *a;
}
int main()
{
    //printf("%p\n", &f()); 
    vector<int> v{3};
    printf("%p\n", &(*(v.begin())));
}
```

I cannot take address of the f(), If I comment "printf("%p\n", &f()); " out I will get error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand.
but how is it possible to take address of *(v.begin())? Isn't * operator the same as a function?

Comment: `*(v.begin())` is the first `int` element in the vector and has a valid address.

Comment: `*(v.begin())` is a `int&`. `f()` is an `int`.

Comment: @MikeVine Are you sure that *(v.begin()) is a int& instead of int?

Comment: @wohlstad but the *a is also allocated on heap which has a valid address

Comment: `f` does not return the heap-allocated object (which is actually leaked). It returns a temporary copy of the `int` value.

Comment: ok, so how is the * operator of std::vector able to return the first element directly? @wohlstad

Comment: @DevSolar Err, no. Try it: `std::is_same<decltype(*v.begin()), int>::value`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I was referring to the OP's comment (one comment above mine) that mentioned that what `f` returns - _"*a is also allocated on heap"_ (which is incorrect).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I stand corrected. The standard says "*convertible to* T", and somehow I mentally dropped the "convertible to". CppReference.com being wrong as well didn't help. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `f` returns a temporary object of the type int

```
int f()
{
    int* a = new int(3);
    return *a;
}
```

You may not apply the address of operator for a temporary object.

You could return a reference to the created dynamically object like for example

```
int & f()
{
    int* a = new int(3);
    return *a;
}
```

And in this case this call of `printf` written like

```
printf("%p\n", ( void * )&f());
```

will be correct.

As for this expression `&(*(v.begin()))` then the dereferencing operator does return a reference to the pointed object by the iterator.

Comment: So the correct answer should be : the * operator of vector return by reference. Thank you!

Comment: @DevSolar In my answer there is clear written that "dereferencing operator does return a reference to the pointed object by the iterator". So your comment does not make sense. As for the function f then it returns the reference obtained by dereferencing the pointer to the dynamically allocated object in the return statement. It is a full analogy with dereferencing the iterator returned by the member function  begin.

Comment: @DevSolar Yeah you are right, v.begin() returns vector::iterator. But this is not I wanted to know. What I take away from this answer is that the dereferencing operator returns a reference.

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot take address of the f(), If I comment "printf("%p\n", &f()); " out I will get error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand

We cannot take the address of `f()` because `f` returns **by value** which means that the expression `f()` is an **rvalue** of type `int` which can't be the operand of the `&` since the operator `&` requires an *lvalue* operand which `f()` is not. This is exactly what the error says.

---

> how is it possible to take address of *(v.begin())?

On the other hand, `std::vector::begin` returns an iterator to the first element of the vector(in case vector is non empty). Then applying `*` on `v.begin()` gives us that first element itself( i.e `*(v.begin())` is an **lvalue**) whose address we can take.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments dereferencing interators returns a *reference*, i.e. a construct similar to a pointer (technically, under the hoods) – you now can take the address of `*v.begin()` (you don't need parentheses around, `.` has higher precedence than `*` anyway) because taking the address of a reference means taking the address of the referred object, which in this case is the first `int` of the vector. This is just the same as taking the address of a normal object or of the first element in an array, as if, *within* `f`, you did `&a[0]`.

On the other hand `f` itself returns a *value* – this is just a temporary object that doesn't have a valid address (potentially at least – the value might be returned, according to calling convention, on the stack, then it does have an address, but as well in a CPU register, then there simply is no adress). This value first needs to be assigned to a variable so that you indeed can take the address of.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed `v.begin()` returns `rvalue iterator` so `&v.begin()` will not work. But dereference operator of `itirator` `*v.begin()` returns `const int&` which in turn is `lvalue` reference what allows to call `addressof` on it.